# Math.Net set Vector<int> size

Tags: c#, .net, math

I want to initiate a `Vector<int>` and set its size using the Math.Net library in C# so I can fill it with data later on. 
If I try `Vector<int> newvector = Vector<int>.Build.Dense(20);` I get an exception saying:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in
>   ReadSheetMusic.exe but was not handled in user code

It works if I make the Vector a float or double though. But for now I don't need decimal precision for my application. I assume there are other ways to set the size of a vector and/ or matrix but I cannot find an alternatives to any .Build methods on the Math.Net website.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add try/catch block and check the Exception information.
In this case it's:

> {"Matrices and vectors of type 'Int32' are not supported. Only Double,
>   Single, Complex or Complex32 are supported at this point."}

So using Double/Single is the only option for now.